# How to set up Hierarchical Zend Rest Routes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-rest, zend-rest-route

With the Zend Framework, I am trying to build routes for a REST api on resources organized in the following pattern:

- http://example.org/users/
- http://example.org/users/234
- http://example.org/users/234/items
- http://example.org/users/234/items/34

How do I set up this with Zend_Rest_Route?

Here is how I have setup the route for the users resource (users/:id) in my bootstrap.php file:

```
  $this->bootstrap('frontController');
  $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController);
  $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('default', $restRoute);
```

[As far as I understand, this is a catch all route so users/324/items/34 would results in parameters set as id=324 and items=34 and everything would be mapped to the Users (front module) Model. From there I guess I could just test for the items parameter and retrieve the item #34 for user #324 on a get request.]<=== I just checked it and it doesn't seems to work like that:

Acessing /users/234/items/43 and

```
var_dump($this->_getAllParams());
```

in the get action of the rest controller results in the following output:

```
array(4) {
 ["controller"]=> string(5) "users"
 ["action"]=>  string(3) "get"
 [2]=>  string(5) "items"  ["module"]=>  string(7) "default"]
}
```

Somehow both ids got lost...

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no feature in Zend_Rest_Route which allows you to do something like this. There is a proposal but not sure when it'll be implemented. You can add this in your Bootstrap to set up this custom route.

```
$front = $this->getResource('FrontController'); 
$testRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'users/:user_id/items/:item_id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'item',
        'module' => 'default'
    )
);

$front->getRouter()->addRoute('test', $testRoute);
```

**user_id** or **item_id** become available in itemAction in UsersController as parameters:

```
$user_id = $this->_request->getParam('user_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You are right I finally had to give up Zend_Rest_Route as the current implementation does not support such a scheme. I finally went the Zend_Controller_Router_Route with Chains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250353/how-do-i-write-chains-of-chains-of-of-route-in-a-ini-file-for-the-zend-framew

Answer (score 6):

I open sourced the solution into github and as a composer package. see https://github.com/aporat/Application_Rest_Controller_Route.

I added a new class which extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route and adds abiliy to add custom restful routes, such as

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('users-messages', new Application_Rest_Controller_Route($frontController, 'users/:user_id/messages', ['controller' => 'users-messages']));
```

Comment: Thanks! Funny thing is, I initially wanted to use this for my URL `users/:user_id/messages`, which was the exact URL in your example!

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Rest_Route maps the first parameter after the controller name to 'id' only when there is 1 parameter.

Best solution I've come up with is to subclass Zend_Rest_Route and override the match() function.  Copy Zend_Rest_Route's match function, but add the following just before the  "Digest URI Params" comment (about 60 lines in).

```
if($pathElementCount > 1 && $path[0] != 'id') {
    $params['id'] = urldecode($path[0]);
    array_shift($path);
}
```

That should give you the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I have done what you say. But then, how do you use it? I was expecting something like this in my routes.init routes.tasktypesstatus.map.1 = "type_id" but it does not work :/

Comment: This solution is perfect.  Works like a charm.  Just need to create your class to extend the Zend_Rest_Route.  Should include the constructor and match functions.