# Zend Framework - Custom defined routes overridden when adding Zend_Rest_Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, zend-rest-route

I'm creating an application that exposes a RESTful API in a module called `api`. For the other modules I created a little class that returns a `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` object with custom defined routes:

```
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
foreach ($this->_modules as $module) {
    if ($module === 'api') continue;
    foreach ($this->_getConfigFiles($module) as $filename) {
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini($filename, 'routes');
        $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
    }
}
return $router;
```

For the default module I have the following route:

```
[routes]
routes.default_index_index.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route
routes.default_index_index.route = /
routes.default_index_index.defaults.module = default
routes.default_index_index.defaults.controller = index
routes.default_index_index.defaults.action = index
```

Now, in my `Bootstrap` file file I have the following:

```
$router = Shark_Module_Loader::getInstance()->getRouter();
$frontController->setRouter($router);
$frontController->getRouter()->removeDefaultRoutes();
$apiRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController, array(), array('api'));
$router->addRoute('rest', $apiRoute);
```

If I skip adding the rest route everything works fine for the default module, of course. But when I add the RESTful route the routes defined in the router are overridden(?), so the current route in the `index` action of the `index` controller of the `default` module (`$this->getFrontController()->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute();`) is an instance of Zend_Rest_Route. Thus, when trying to access a custom route defined in on of the route config files, lets say:

```
...
routes.default_pages_view.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route
routes.default_pages_view.route = /view/:page
routes.default_pages_view.defaults.module = default
routes.default_pages_view.defaults.controller = pages
routes.default_pages_view.defaults.action = view
...
```

I get a 404 error saying that the request action (`get`) is not present.

I already went through the docs and didn't see any hint that suggests this behavior.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this out of the box. (Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2204653/678455))

You need to extend the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` class. I've done it like this:

```
class Mauro_Controller_Router_Route_Method extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route {

    protected $_method;

    public function __construct($route, $defaults = array(), $reqs = array(), Zend_Translate $translator = null, $locale = null) {
        list($this->_method, $route) = explode(' ', $route, 2);
        parent::__construct($route, $defaults, $reqs, $translator, $locale);
    }

    public function match($path, $partial = false) {
        $requestMethod = $this->getRequest()->getMethod();
        $requestMethod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('method')
            ? strtoupper($this->getRequest()->getParam('method'))
            : $requestMethod;
        return $requestMethod == strtoupper($this->_method)
            ? parent::match($path, $partial)
            : false;
    }

    protected function getRequest() {
        return Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
    }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
$router->addRoute( new Mauro_Controller_Router_Route_Method( 'GET /view/:page', array( 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view' ), array( 'page' => '/d+', ) ) );
```

Comment: That's a good approach. I could set up the route with the custom type in the ini files. That's more or less the way routes are defined in rails, right?

Comment: Yeah, that would require that you add the `getInstance()` method to it. It's what Zend_Application uses to instance routes and get them configured using the .ini. I don't use the .ini for this often since it would be enormous :P.