# Zend Rest Route - how to create hierarchical URLs?

Tags: zend-framework, rest, hierarchical, zend-rest-route

I'm developing an API using Zend Framework 1.12.3. I'm using Zend_Rest_Route, but I would like to have hierarchical URLs:

- http://api.example.com/professors
- http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId
- http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId/subjects
- http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId/subjects/:subjectId

I'm considering of using this approach, since I'd have to assign certain subjects to certain professors, and I belive that this schema solves it neatly.

However, I'm having a hard time achieving hierarchical URLs. I've already tried:

1. Zend_Controller_Router_Route with Chains, in the config .ini file, but since both the controller and the action have to be specified, when accessing http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId/subjects it always pointed to the same action (i.e., whatever the call method was - POST, PUT, GET, DELETE - it always pointed to the action specified in the config .ini file). For example, had I specified the getAction in the config file, using chains it would always call the getAction, no matter what was the method I've used. Currently, when having a POST call, it actually calls the postAction() (similarly happens for PUT, GET, DELETE, PATCH, HEAD and OPTIONS). My Controller file looks like this:

   ```
   class V1_ProfessorsController extends REST_Controller
   {
           public function optionsAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function headAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function indexAction()
           {
                   // code goes here - list of resources
           }

           public function getAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function postAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function putAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function patchAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

           public function deleteAction()
           {
                   // code goes here
           }

   }
   ```
2. Subclassing the Zend_Rest_Route and overriding the match() function as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474171/1988372). The thing is, that while this does work when calling `http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId/subjects`, it still uses the same ProfessorsController that is used when calling `http://api.example.com/professors`. I'm not sure about this, but I believe that it would be best having its own controller (e.g. ProfessorsSubjectsController).

Also, I've got a question. How should the hierarchical routes work? Would it be better to have different controllers for different resources/subresources? E.g., having ProfessorsController for `http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId` and ProfessorsSubjectsController for `http://api.example.com/professors/:professorId/subjects/:subjectId` ?

Comment: Any progress in finding an answer on this? Struggeling with the same problem.

Comment: @Gabriel Unfortunately, not yet. I'm developing other parts of the API, and I thought I'd leave the hierarchical URLs last. 

If I find a solution, I'll post it here. I'd appreciate it if you do the same.

Comment: Will do. Im checking if there might be a solution to use chained routes.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I've got a solution for this..

Comment: @Gabriel could you please share the solution? It would be great for both myself and any others that face the same issue.

Comment: shared my solution below..

Comment: I have same problem. Anyone have solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution somewhere that I modified slightly. This is a custom route class that does what I think we both want it to do.

```
<?php 

require_once "modules.inc";

class Rest_Controller_Route extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route
{

/**
 * @var Zend_Controller_Front
 */
protected $_front;

protected $_actionKey     = 'action';

/**
 * Prepares the route for mapping by splitting (exploding) it
 * to a corresponding atomic parts. These parts are assigned
 * a position which is later used for matching and preparing values.
 *
 * @param Zend_Controller_Front $front Front Controller object
 * @param string $route Map used to match with later submitted URL path
 * @param array $defaults Defaults for map variables with keys as variable names
 * @param array $reqs Regular expression requirements for variables (keys as variable names)
 * @param Zend_Translate $translator Translator to use for this instance
 */
public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Front $front, $route, $defaults = array(), $reqs = array(), Zend_Translate $translator = null, $locale = null)
{
    $this->_front      = $front;
    $this->_dispatcher = $front->getDispatcher();

    parent::__construct($route, $defaults, $reqs, $translator, $locale);
}



/**
 * Matches a user submitted path with parts defined by a map. Assigns and
 * returns an array of variables on a successful match.
 *
 * @param string $path Path used to match against this routing map
 * @return array|false An array of assigned values or a false on a mismatch
 */
public function match($path, $partial = false)
{

    $return = parent::match($path, $partial);

    // add the RESTful action mapping
    if ($return) {
        $request = $this->_front->getRequest();
        $path   = $request->getPathInfo();
        $params = $request->getParams();

        $path   = trim($path, '/');

        if ($path != '') {
            $path = explode('/', $path);
        }

        $lastParam = array_pop($path);

        // Determine Action
        $requestMethod = strtolower($request->getMethod());
        if ($requestMethod == 'head') {
            if (is_numeric($lastParam)) {
                $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'head';
                $return["id"] = $lastParam;
            }
        } else if ($requestMethod != 'get') {
            if ($request->getParam('_method')) {
                $return[$this->_actionKey] = strtolower($request->getParam('_method'));
            } elseif ( $request->getHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override') ) {
                $return[$this->_actionKey] = strtolower($request->getHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
            } else {
                $return[$this->_actionKey] = $requestMethod;
            }

            // Map PUT, DELETE and POST to actual create/update/delete actions
            // based on parameter count (posting to resource or collection)
            switch( $return[$this->_actionKey] ){
                case 'post':
                    $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'post';
                    break;
                case 'put':
                    $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'put';
                    $return["id"] = $lastParam;
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'delete';
                    $return["id"] = $lastParam;
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // if the last argument in the path is a numeric value, consider this request a GET of an item
            if (is_numeric($lastParam)) {
                $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'get';
                $return["id"] = $lastParam;
            } else {
                if (isset($data[0]) && is_numeric($data[0])) {
                    $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'get';
                    $return["id"] = $lastParam;
                } else {
                    $return[$this->_actionKey] = 'index';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;

}

}
```

To use this, create all your routes like this in your bootstrap or index.php, two examples:

```
$route = new Rest_Controller_Route($front, 'customers/*', array('controller' => 'customers'));
$router->addRoute('customers', $route);

$route = new Rest_Controller_Route($front, 'customers/:customer_id/documents/*', array('controller' => 'customers-documents'));
$router->addRoute('customersdocuments', $route);
```

This works as a charm for me. Thou, consider that this is not my final solution so there might be dragons that I haven't discovered so be aware. :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution. It seems to be working, but I think I need to change some settings in my Zend environment.

I've been using Zend_Rest_Route in application.ini
But in order for your solution to work, I need to stop using this Zend_Rest_Route, and thus it tries to find the index/get/put/post/patch/delete .phtml files in the views folder.

Comment: Also, it seems that I cannot send parameters in the body (e.g. curl -v -X http://api.example.com/customers -d foo=bar).

Comment: That is weird, since Im doing it.. Im not familiar with curl, I use a Firefox plugin to do this. Is it a get operation you do or what?

Comment: It happens on any kind of operation, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE. I should be able to send parameters in the body via -d, but it must be something wrong with my environment, because it does call the right controller. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: not yet, but I think I know why I can't read the params from the body. I'll post the solution once I'll solve it.